# can i create more than one Union between three select statements?

Tags: sql

I would like to create two union operators between three select statements to be able to authenticate users trying to log in into my database application in oracle apex. is it possible or not and if it is how is the correct way to do it?

```
select 'USER'
from customers
where upper(cid) = upper(:p_username) and c_pass = :p_password
UNION 
select 'employee'
from employees
where upper(e_un) = upper(:p_username) and e_pass = :p_password;
UNION 
select 'manager'
from employees 
where upper(e_un) = upper(:p_username) and e_pass = :p_password and e_type='MANAGER';
```

Comment: This should work. Why don't you give it a try and let us know if you have a problem with this code?

Comment: If you remove the `;` after the `WHERE` clause of the second query, the syntax should be OK.

Comment: As many `UNION`, `INTERSECT`, and `EXCEPT` as you want. You don't mention the specific database, but the engine may have some restrictions on them.

Answer (score 0):

In a word, yes, it's possible.

You're more or less on the right track, although I'd use case-sensitive comparisons of the username and password, and use `union all` instead of `union` for better performance.